# How to add timer to bootstrap progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a timer with the progress bar. the timer works fine. but I want to move the progress bar with the timer. I'm using the bootstrap progress bar. if I remove the bar variable from the function the timer works fine but with the progress, it stops working. any suggestions? thank you :)

```js
function startTimer(duration, display, bar) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        bar.css('width', minutes + '%');

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var minutes = 60 * 15,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    bar = document.querySelector('#progressBar');
    startTimer(minutes, display, bar);
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="progress mx-auto mb-2" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" id="progressBar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<span id="time">15:00</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bar.style.width`, `.css()` is a `jQuery` function.

For correct percentage, calculate total and remaining seconds and set bar width based on that

```js
function startTimer(duration, display, bar) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        
        var totalSeconds = 15 * 60
        , remainingSeconds = minutes * 60 + seconds
        
        bar.style.width = (remainingSeconds*100/totalSeconds) + "%";
        
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var minutes = 60 * 15,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    bar = document.querySelector('#progressBar');
    startTimer(minutes, display, bar);
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="progress mx-auto mb-2" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" id="progressBar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<span id="time">15:00</span>
```

Comment: thank you. this works. but any idea of how to make the progress bar move with timer. eg the timer is 15 minutes now. after 15 mins it should be empty.

Comment: It works but kinda buggy.. it starts from `10000%` and in the middle instead of `50%` it goes to `5000%`. any idea why?

Comment: Move the portion that calculates percentages above the portion that converts the values to strings, that is causing the issue. Check the edit